# Google Map APIs do not work in Angular view

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-maps, autocomplete

I am trying to use Google map apis in order to obtain a simple autocomplete function for an "Place" input box. I am using angular routing.

Following the instructions for developers given by Google, in the `<head>` of the main template I have:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
<script src="js/googleAutocomplete.js"></script>
```

where googleAutocomplete.js is

```
function initializeGoogleApi() {
    var input = document.getElementById('CityInput');
    var options = {
        types: ['(cities)']
    };
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
}
```

and in one of the views I have

```
<input id="CityInput" type="text" name="place" ng-model="profile.place">
```

This input field is supposed to have autocomplete services from Google apis, but it is not working.

However, if I place the input box in the main template (i.e., not in the view), the autocomplete function works.

I cannot figure out what goes wrong in the view. I tried putting `onload="initializeGoogleApi()"`
both in the `body` tag (main template), and in the outer `div` of the view, with no success.

Any suggestions? 
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe create a plunker or post the minimal working code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html in the view isn't in the DOM until it's selected, so the input box doesn't exist when the body's onload events triggered. input, in initializeGoogleApi, is null...

Onload doesn't work on divs. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp).

The only way I could get it to work was to put the initialize in the controller of that route.

Comment: Thanks, now I think I understand the problem.

About putting the initialize in the controller, do you mean something like:


`$scope.initialize=function(){...};`


and the calling:


`$scope.initialize();`?


If so, how would you select the input text? 


`var input = document.getElementById('CityInput');`

or maybe using `ng-model`?

Comment: I put `$scope.initialize=function(){...};`, calling `$scope.initialize();` when the view is loaded. I get the autocompleted value of the input box with `document.getElementById('CityInput').value;`.
Everything works perfectly.